# Extract dirty rects RGB pixel buffer data DirectX

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11, dxgi

I'm using Desktop Duplication from Windows API.
Here is the code to access next frame and get the rectangle of pixels that have change from previous frame.

```
//
// Get next frame and write it into Data
//
_Success_(*Timeout == false && return == DUPL_RETURN_SUCCESS)
DUPL_RETURN DUPLICATIONMANAGER::GetFrame(_Out_ FRAME_DATA* Data, _Out_ bool* Timeout)
{
IDXGIResource* DesktopResource = nullptr;
DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO FrameInfo;

// Get new frame
HRESULT hr = m_DeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(10000, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);
if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    *Timeout = true;
    return DUPL_RETURN_SUCCESS;
}
*Timeout = false;

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return ProcessFailure(m_Device, L"Failed to acquire next frame in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", hr, FrameInfoExpectedErrors);
}

// If still holding old frame, destroy it
if (m_AcquiredDesktopImage)
{
    m_AcquiredDesktopImage->Release();
    m_AcquiredDesktopImage = nullptr;
}

// QI for IDXGIResource
hr = DesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&m_AcquiredDesktopImage));
DesktopResource->Release();
DesktopResource = nullptr;
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return ProcessFailure(nullptr, L"Failed to QI for ID3D11Texture2D from acquired IDXGIResource in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", hr);
}

// Get metadata
if (FrameInfo.TotalMetadataBufferSize)
{
    // Old buffer too small
    if (FrameInfo.TotalMetadataBufferSize > m_MetaDataSize)
    {
        if (m_MetaDataBuffer)
        {
            delete [] m_MetaDataBuffer;
            m_MetaDataBuffer = nullptr;
        }
        m_MetaDataBuffer = new (std::nothrow) BYTE[FrameInfo.TotalMetadataBufferSize];
        if (!m_MetaDataBuffer)
        {
            m_MetaDataSize = 0;
            Data->MoveCount = 0;
            Data->DirtyCount = 0;
            return ProcessFailure(nullptr, L"Failed to allocate memory for metadata in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", E_OUTOFMEMORY);
        }
        m_MetaDataSize = FrameInfo.TotalMetadataBufferSize;
    }

    UINT BufSize = FrameInfo.TotalMetadataBufferSize;

    // Get move rectangles
    hr = m_DeskDupl->GetFrameMoveRects(BufSize, reinterpret_cast<DXGI_OUTDUPL_MOVE_RECT*>(m_MetaDataBuffer), &BufSize);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        Data->MoveCount = 0;
        Data->DirtyCount = 0;
        return ProcessFailure(nullptr, L"Failed to get frame move rects in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", hr, FrameInfoExpectedErrors);
    }
    Data->MoveCount = BufSize / sizeof(DXGI_OUTDUPL_MOVE_RECT);

    BYTE* DirtyRects = m_MetaDataBuffer + BufSize;
    BufSize = FrameInfo.TotalMetadataBufferSize - BufSize;

    // Get dirty rectangles
    hr = m_DeskDupl->GetFrameDirtyRects(BufSize, reinterpret_cast<RECT*>(DirtyRects), &BufSize);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        Data->MoveCount = 0;
        Data->DirtyCount = 0;
        return ProcessFailure(nullptr, L"Failed to get frame dirty rects in DUPLICATIONMANAGER", L"Error", hr, FrameInfoExpectedErrors);
    }
    Data->DirtyCount = BufSize / sizeof(RECT);

    Data->MetaData = m_MetaDataBuffer;
}

Data->Frame = m_AcquiredDesktopImage;
Data->FrameInfo = FrameInfo;

//Here I would like to access pixel data from Data->Frame. A buffer of RGBA pixel

return DUPL_RETURN_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is `Frame_Data` structure

```
typedef struct _FRAME_DATA
{
ID3D11Texture2D* Frame;
DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO FrameInfo;
_Field_size_bytes_((MoveCount * sizeof(DXGI_OUTDUPL_MOVE_RECT)) + (DirtyCount * sizeof(RECT))) BYTE* MetaData;
UINT DirtyCount;
UINT MoveCount;
} FRAME_DATA;
```

Is it possible to access pixel buffer data that have been modified from `Data->Frame`

Here is my code to access data :

```
BYTE* DISPLAYMANAGER::GetImageData(ID3D11Texture2D* texture2D, D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC Desc)
{
if (texture2D != NULL)
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
    texture2D->GetDesc(&description);
    description.BindFlags = 0;
    description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    description.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;

    ID3D11Texture2D* texTemp = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &texTemp);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (texTemp)
        {
            texTemp->Release();
            texTemp = NULL;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    m_DeviceContext->CopyResource(texTemp, texture2D);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
    unsigned int subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
    hr = m_DeviceContext->Map(texTemp, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &mapped);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        texTemp->Release();
        texTemp = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned char *captureData = new unsigned char[Desc.Width * Desc.Height * 4];
    RtlZeroMemory(captureData, Desc.Width * Desc.Height * 4);
    const int pitch = mapped.RowPitch;
    unsigned char *source = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mapped.pData);
    unsigned char *dest = captureData;
    for (int i = 0; i < Desc.Height; i++) {
        memcpy(captureData, source, Desc.Width * 4);
        source += pitch;
        captureData += Desc.Width * 4;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Desc.Width * Desc.Height * 4; i++) {
        //trace(L"Pixel[%d] = %x\n", i, dest[i]);
    }

    m_DeviceContext->Unmap(texTemp, 0);
    return dest;
}
else
    return NULL;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The textures you obtain via duplication API are not necessarily accessible for CPU, for individual pixel access. To read the texture data, you might need to create a mappable staging texture and copy the obtained texture there. Then doing the mapping you would get a pointer to actual data. Note that this is, in general, not a performance friendly operation.

You will find related information in other answers as well:

[How to work with pixels using Direct2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22217372/868014):

> For those times when you absolutely have to do CPU pixel manipulation but still want a substantial degree of acceleration, you can manage your own mappable D3D11 textures. For example, you can use staging textures if you want to asynchronously manipulate your texture resources from the CPU.

[Transferring textures across adapters in DirectX 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321167/transferring-textures-across-adapters-in-directx-11):

> ... copies it to a staging resource (created on the same device) using ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource. I then map that staging resource with Read...

Comment: Hello Roman thank you for your help. I edited my post with what I did but I got '0' everywhere... I call "GetImageData" after the "Process Frame" function from this sample https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a/sourcecode?fileId=42782&pathId=1384140008

Comment: The updated code snippet is about right. I thought `CopyResource` could fail for some reason, however it is not clear just from code why it would do that.

Comment: Yes ... It's a problem. I don't know why it fails.. Even mapped.pData got null values everywhere. Maybe should I add a flag on the description ?